# SearchResultsLayoutPage error in enterprise search site after SP1 and several CU's installed all at once

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, search-results

After applying patches to our SharePoint 2013 farm several of our enterprise search sites now throw this error `The base type 'Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Internal.UI.SearchResultsLayoutPage' is not allowed for this page. The type Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Internal.UI.SearchResultsLayoutPage, Microsoft.Office.Server.Search, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c could not be found or it is not registered as safe.` Even when attempting to create a new search results page from the pages directory then attempting to navigate to the page the same error is thrown. These sites are publishing sites as well. The Logs have not been helpful either only stating the same error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Either add the safecontrol to your config file or update the SearchResults.aspx page layout's top section.

```
<%@ Page language="C#" Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingLayoutPage,Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing,Version=15.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="OSRVWC" Namespace="Microsoft.Office.Server.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.Office.Server, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="OSRVUPWC" Namespace="Microsoft.Office.Server.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SPSWC" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SEARCHWC" Namespace="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="PublishingWebControls" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
```

See the following link: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/c024ee28-35ef-473c-85a5-181bc3c68c37/parser-error-when-trying-to-use-enterprise-search?forum=sharepointsearch

Comment: Adding the safecontrol line to the config file resolved the issue. Any idea why that is needed after the patches?

Comment: Added SafeControl from second answer of link provided to fix our issue on 2016 farm post September patches.

Comment: Thanks, worked for SP2019 too.

Answer (score 1):

My `searchresults.aspx` page located at `/_catalogs/masterpage` was edited. After I restored it back to site definition the error disappeared.

Just right click on the file and choose `Reset to site definition`

Answer (score 1):

I gleaned my answer from this post:
http://www.sharepointassist.com/2011/10/20/sharepoint-error-code-blocks-are-not-allowed-in-this-file/

I had tinkered with the pages, but nothing that I needed to save. On my intranet site, I went to my Search Site Collection and under Site Settings I went to the Site Actions section and clicked "Reset to site definition" this fixed the issue of the "Code blocks are not allowed in this file" error.

Next I went to my Central Administration and followed the same procedure, resetting to the site definition for the Central Admin site collection.

Just know that this will wipe out any customizations. I didn't have any customizations on my SC's, so I didn't worry about it.

Hope this helps!
Nick

Answer (score 0):

I have issued the same bug with sandbox solution

my needs are to deploy a new customized searchresults page

The workaround that worked for me was to delete the first line

```
<%@ Page language="C#" Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingLayoutPage,Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing,Version=15.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
```

and add some missing references :

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingLayoutPage,Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing,Version=16.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>

<%@ Register TagPrefix="SharePointWebControls" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
```

for my needs I deleted the code using `<% %>` and added my custom css

it gives something like :

```
    <%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="OSRVWC" Namespace="Microsoft.Office.Server.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.Office.Server, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="OSRVUPWC" Namespace="Microsoft.Office.Server.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SPSWC" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SEARCHWC" Namespace="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="PublishingWebControls" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>



<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingLayoutPage,Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing,Version=16.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>

<%@ Register TagPrefix="SharePointWebControls" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>



<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">
<SharePoint:StyleBlock runat="server"> 
    #searchIcon
    { 
        display: none !important; 
    }

</SharePoint:StyleBlock>
</asp:Content>
```

after all that I had to add webparts in elements.xml for pages :

[image]